# system() function in PHP prints variable 2 times

Tags: php, function, system

Stupid question, this code:

```
<?php
$variable = system("cat /home/maxor/test.txt");
echo $variable;
?>
```

with file test.txt:

```
blah
```

prints:

```
blah
blah
```

What can I do with system() function to not print nothing so I get 1 "blah"???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `exec` instead of `system`

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#94262

Answer (score 7):

`system` displays whatever the program outputs and returns the last line of output.

`exec` displays nothing and returns the last line of output.

`passthru` displays whatever the program outputs and returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual -- see **[`system()`](https://www.php.net/system)** :

> `system()` is just like the C version
> of the function in that it executes
> the given command and **outputs the
> result**.

Which explains the first `blah`

And :

> **Returns the last line of the command
> output** on success

And you are echoing the returned value -- which explains the second `blah`.

If you want to execute a command, and get the full output to a variable, you should take a look at **[`exec`][2]**, or **[`shell_exec`][3]**.

The first one will get you all the lines of the output to an array *(see the second paramater)* ; and the second one will get you the full output as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `exec` instead.  To get all the output, rather than just the last line do this:

```
$variable = array();
$lastline = exec("cat /home/maxor/test.txt", $variable);
echo implode("\n", $variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`system` is calling the actual `cat` program, which is outputting "blah" from `test.txt`. It also returns the value back to `$variable` which you're then printing out again.

Use [`exec`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#94262) or [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead of system.